# Prepopulate HTML form based on previous field

Tags: php, html, forms

I currently have a very simple HTML form that looks something like this:

```
<form>
   <label for="faccountNumber">Account Number</label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="faccountNumber"><br><br>
   <label for="ffirstName">First Name</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ffirstName"><br><br>
   <label for="fsurname">Surname</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fsurname"><br><br>
</form>
```

I would like to prepopulate some values dependent on the account number entered. This is just for a mockup & so I just want to hardcode in a few examples.

For example, if the account number `1789`was entered I would like to automatically prepopulate the first name as `John` & the surname as `Smith`. How can I do this?

Comment: I *wouldn't* to be honest ... what would stop John Smith from entering 1790 as the account number and, potentially, getting the valid registered forename/surname of another user? At the very least that's an information leak.

Comment: @CD001 The example I've used above is completely made up & only functionally represents what I want to do, not the actual scenario but I appreciate your concern about data protection.

Comment: is it wordpress?

Comment: @JoeBarrett Nope, it's for a small company internal dashboard for generating invoices.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the page is in an authenticated context, otherwise you'll have security problems.
The task should be done in a php page.

```
/*   
 - get the user id from $_GET or anywhere you hold that info  
 - query the database for name and surname, filtering with the retrieved id  
 - assign values to $name and $surname variables  
*/    
<form>
   <label for="faccountNumber">Account Number</label>
   <input type="number" class="form-control" id="faccountNumber"><br><br>
   <label for="ffirstName">First Name</label>
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $surname;?>" class="form-control" id="ffirstName"><br><br>
   <label for="fsurname">Surname</label>
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $surname;?>" class="form-control" id="fsurname"><br><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some javascript, this is rough solution using jquery:

```
$("#faccountNumber").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    let accountNum = $(this).val();
    if (accountNum == 1789) {
        $('#ffirstName').val("John");
        $('#fsurname').val("Smith");
    }           
});
```

If you want to make it more dynamic, you can fetch the data with ajax, but like **CD001** said in the comments, you should avoid doing stuff like this for any sensitive data.